Do dragons that act in opposition to their species alignment experience physical changes that reflect it?
To clarify there are Chromatic Dragons which are always evil and Metallic Dragons which are always good but lets assume that a silver dragon started acting evil. Would the silver dragon have their scales lose their metallic hue or otherwise develop some sort of change that keeps the 'color coded for convenience' vibe dragons have going on?

Which edition(s) are relevant to your question? There lore hasn't changed much, but knowing which editions' books we should quote from would make it easier to write answers.

You used the Dragonlance tag, but you do not refer to such setting in your question: are you interested in this specific world? Or is yours a more general question, spanning all the campaign settings?

No, or at least probably not
There is one possible exception, but that exception is described as unique. Otherwise, dragons who change alignment still continue to have the same color/biology that they always did.
Never as part of the game rules
I can’t back this up, really, since all I can really do is gesture at 50+ years of books and say “it’s not in there,” but, well, it’s not.
In particular, the latest edition of D&D has taken pains to emphasize that dragons are only “generally” their listed alignment, so a dragon not matching their color coding is allowed under the rules. Nothing says they will ever change into some other kind of dragon.
This isn’t actually a change, even though prior editions would use words like “always” for describing dragon alignment. For example, see our Q&A on dragon alignment in the “v.3.5 revised edition” of D&D. The latest version is just clearer about the existence of exceptions.
Once in a novel
The Dragonlance novel The Gully Dwarves (1996) focuses on a reformed green dragon, rejected by Takhisis, Verden Leafglow. Verden Leafglow took on a “verdigris” or “amber” hue, and was eventually “reborn” as a bronze dragon through the divine intervention of Reorx.
The divine interaction here is notable, and might suggest some things about dragon alignment in Dragonlance. In particular, the rejection by Takhisis happened first, which might suggest that if Takhisis hadn’t rejected Verden, Verden would have remained evil and green. Maybe. It’s not clearly indicated, that I can tell, and there aren’t any other Dragonlance instances we can really compare here. But we also don’t know if a nearly-thirty-year-old novel is even considered canon anymore; Dragonlance has been in a weird limbo for most of the time since due to the legal battles between Wizards of the Coast and Margaret Weis/Tracy Hickman.

With thanks to @afroakuma for confirming this and pointing out the exception in The Gully Dwarves.

There's no rule about it, maybe, but does it make sense in your world? If you're the game master the question you want to ask is does it make the game more fun to play if it's true - this might be because it makes for a more internally consistent world, or just helps give a clue that something is not as expected. Maybe it's not a strict color change, but a silver dragon that's been doing evil deeds would probably tarnish, and might have tell-tale supplies of silver polish around to try to stay shiny. The next question you'd have to ask is, do their powers change if their color changes... i.e. do they really just become a chromatic dragon of some sort. Where do dragon powers really come from, anyway...
If you have the outer appearance reflect inner change then you have to ask does this happen to everyone? So... if someone's evil, you can tell just by looking? Or does it only happen to dragons because... why?
Old DnD rules had pretty fixed alignments for everything except players. More recent versions of the game leave space for good and bad versions of any thinking critter, which is a relief, but really think about why it would make sense for the appearance of a creature to change because they changed alignment. Maybe dragons really are effectively channels of the power of the 'ultimate' dragons (Chromatic and Platinum) and so when a dragon changes alignment, they change where their power comes from and it naturally follows that they'll change form, but then it would make sense that "All Silver Dragons Are Good" is true, because any Evil ones would have changed to a colored dragon form...
